# Why can't I delete my SR account?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I have an account on SR:

[image]

As you can see I haven't posted any content, and normally if so, there should be a 'Delete' button where the 'Edit', 'Privileges', etc. buttons are, but it isn't! How can I delete my SR account?

Answer (score 5):

You've posted two things, [a question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10519/chat-script-with-mac-client) and [an answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10521/how-to-send-a-large-mms-for-free-from-a-pc/10522#10522) (both currently deleted). I believe this is what's keeping you from self-deleting your account. If you really want your account here deleted:

1. We'll miss you :(
2. You can use the [Contact Us](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/contact) link at the bottom of every page to contact people that can delete your account for you.

Comment: Oh, that's weird. On sites where I deleted content I was able to delete my account after... thanks for the answer :)